# Installing KDE alongside Unity

Tags: unity, kubuntu, kde, dependencies, kde5

I am using Ubuntu 15.10 and i would like to install Plasma 5.4.I did the following steps:

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kubuntu-ppa/backports
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`

As I am using **Unity** version of Ubuntu,I tried to install **Kubuntu desktop package** :

`sudo apt-get install kubuntu-desktop`

But i am getting following dependecies problem :

`The following packages have unmet dependencies:
kubuntu-desktop:Depends:software-properties-kde but it is not going to be  installed
  Recommends: apport-kde but it is not going to be installed
  Recommends: apturl-kde but it is not going to be installed
  Recommends: kubuntu-driver-manager but it is not going to be installed
  Recommends: kubuntu-notification-helper but it is not going to be installed
  Recommends: muon-discover but it is not going to be installed
  Recommends: muon-notifier but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.`

I tried to handle dependencies by installing these packages one by one :

`apt-get -s install software-properties-kde`

But it gives another dependency error `python3-pyqt5` which in turn gives another dependency error `qtbase-abi-5-4-2`.

Comment: What is the output of 'apt-get -s install software-properties-kde'?